# Where can I get a language helper now that lernu.net has removed that feature?

Tags: learning

Before lernu.net was updated, a large part of the material was corresponding courses: *Ana Pana*, *Ana renkontas* and so on. In each chapter one would read a text, complete a numer of exercises and then write some sentences and send them  to a "language helper". This is where I got started with Esperanto. I found it amazing that someone would work voluntarily as my teacher. On top of that she spoke my native language! She didn't just correct my writing. She anwered my questions and introduced me to the community.

The new content on Lernu is great, but it's a pity that they've removed the language helpers. Is there somewhere else one can find a teacher willing to help the way mine did?

Answer (score 7):

The Free Esperanto Course (FEC) was old when I took it nearly 20 years ago, but it's still up and running. I've always said that the advantage of this course is that it pairs you up with an instructor who can answer your questions. It's still a good course, and most instructors won't limit you to just asking about the current lesson.

http://pacujo.net/esperanto/course/

My son and I are currently putting together a YouTube video course based on FEC in which I present the same material in my own way and then correct exercises that viewers send in. We are currently looking for new learners of any age who would like to go over the basics.

https://youtu.be/FVtBVo29HN0

For those who have mastered the basics - e.g. who have finished the Duolingo Esperanto tree - there is the *[Ekparolu](http://www.edukado.net/ekparolu)* project, which offers 10 free lessons from a personal tutor.

iTalki may be a source for paid and free tutoring in Esperanto. (Or just ask me.)

I find that the Duolingo forum for Esperanto to be a good place to ask questions.

https://www.duolingo.com/topic/915

HiNative is also a good place to ask even the most basic questions.

https://hinative.com/